The eigenvectors associated to the continuous spectrum in Dirac formalism
I am comfused about the definition of an observable, eigenvectors and the spectrum in the physics litterature. All what I did understand from Dirac's monograph is that the state space is a complex vector $\Psi$ space equipped with an inner product $\langle.,.\rangle$ and an observable is a hermitian operators $A: \Psi\rightarrow \Psi$ that have a complet set of eigenvectors. The set of all eigenvalues is called the spectrum and denoted by $\sigma(A)$. My question is the following : Let $A$ be an abservable such that $\sigma(A)=\mathbb{R}$ and let $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$. Do we have, according to Dirac, the existence of a vector $|\lambda\rangle\in \Psi$ such that $A|\lambda\rangle=\lambda |\lambda\rangle$ ?

Dirac is dead, we cannot ask him what he really meant by this. However, the pretension that these eigenstates exist in some sense is prevalent in many texts on quantum mechanics. There are several possibilities to deal with the claim of the existence of eigenstates for values in the spectrum outside the point spectrum.

Just ignore it. This is the approach taken by most introductory texts to quantum mechanics, and most non-mathematical physicists. The results come out right if you don't think too hard about the nature of these "states" and stay away from trying to produce paradoxes with them.

Interpret as shorthand. As in other cases (see this answer of mine about the $\delta$-"function"), the notation $A\lvert \lambda \rangle = \lambda \lvert \lambda\rangle$ may be interpreted as approximative shorthand - what is really meant is that there's a sequence of vectors $\lvert \lambda_i\rangle$ such that $\lim_{i\to\infty} \lvert\lvert A\lvert\lambda_i\rangle - \lambda\lvert \lambda_i\rangle\rvert\rvert = 0$, i.e. that we can get arbitrarily close to begin an eigenvector with that eigenvalue (but the limit $\lim_{i\to\infty} \lvert \lambda_i\rangle$ does not exist inside the Hilbert space in this case).
If you replace every mention of the eigenvector with a statement about this limiting case, you get a statement that rigorous mathematics would prove.

Interpret via rigged Hilbert spaces. As mike stone's answer mentions, there's another formulation where we extend the Hilbert space to a Gel'fand triple with a larger space where the continuous "eigenstates" live. In essence, this is little more than adding the limits $\lim_{i\to\infty}\lvert \lambda_i\rangle$ to the original space: For instance, for the position operator in position representation, the $\lvert \psi_i\rangle$ are square-integrable nascent $\delta$-functions, and their limit in the rigged Hilbert space is the $\delta$ distribution itself. This is a convenient way to retroactively justify the physicists' claim about the existence of these states as actual vectors, but the rigged formalism is little more - in practice, most rigorous functional analysis texts use the limiting approach in my second point if they have to, and largely avoid talking about these approximate eigenstates as much as they can.



As long as you allow elements of the associated rigged Hilbert space the answer is "yes."

In fact, my question is based solely on Dirac formulation as given in his classic monograph. He does not talk about Hilbert space or rigged Hilbert space (which doesnt exist at the time !). I mean, for Dirac at the time, what does he mean by the existence of eigenvectors for every point in the continuous spectrum ? are they actual vectors of his state space $\Psi$ ?

Dirac’s formulation only works if you allow a rigged Hilbert space. In fact, the Dirac delta (an infinitely localized eigenstates) is the key piece  of the theory that makes this requirement obvious.

@MattHanson That is the mathematical point of view, I am ok but what I meant is the following : In Dirac exposition and in the majority of physics textbooks on the subject, do we define observables and eigenvectors that way ? do an eigenvector corresponding to the continuous spectrum is by definition (for Dirac) an element of the state space $\Psi$ ?

That seems like a typical interpretation of what the state vectors are. Just bear in mind that there is a large degree of “arbitrariness” of how we choose to represent the state vectors. For instance, linear combinations of degenerate states are also valid states, and multiplying by a complex exponential does not change the probability density of a state.

Note that eigenstates belonging to any continuous spectrum exists in the rigged Hilbert space, but then it also means that such states are not possible to observe within the framework of quantum theory, which postulates that states of a quantum system must live within a Hilbert space, not rigged. While indeed the concept of rigged Hilbert spaces helps to pin down where these eigenstates live, it turns out nobody managed to make a sensible quantum theory with them, whereas mathematicians proved that Hilbert space stuff is sufficient, and physicists' sloppy use is justified.
